# dnsmasq does not listen to conf file

Tags: osx, dnsmasq

I have installed and started dnsmasq, using `brew install dnsmasq` and `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist` respectively. I tried to use the "adress" function inside `dnsmasq.conf` and added this as an example:

```
address=/.facebook.com/127.0.0.1
```

However, accesing facebook from my browser does not send me to localhost. I also tried starting it and specifying the conf file, but it's in the default path anyway.

It might also be that it doesn't work at all, but there is no way to tell.

Answer (score 1):

First, does the file `/etc/resolv.conf` have a `nameserver` entry with the IP address of the machine running `dnsmasq`? If not, you're browser is just using whatever IP address appears in `/etc/resolv.conf` for a DNS name server. You can discover what IP address your browser is using by running `nslookup` in a terminal window, and issuing the `server` command.

Second, does `dnsmasq.conf` have a `resolv-file` parameter? If you want to use `dnsmasq` to aggregate DNS traffic, or just block certain sites, then you probably want to `mv  /etc/resolv.conf  /etc/dnsmasq.resolv` and then fill in the `resolv-file=/etc/dnsmasq.resolv` parameter.

Don't forget to stop and start `dnsmasq` after these changes.

Comment: My resolv.conf is this (excluding commented lines) `nameserver 10.0.1.1` and this is in dnsmasq.conf `resolv-file=/etc/resolv.conf`. I have had that from the beginning and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set two different DNS servers in the System Preferences, the one positioned at the top being `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Remove the second entry unless it points to a different but identically configured DNS server

Comment: Actually this stopped working now. What a horrible program `dnsmasq` is.

Comment: @roaima If I do that, all webpages I access load forever.

Comment: Then you've not configured it properly yet. If you have two DNS resolvers you get a 50% chance of using your custom one.

Comment: @roaima I've followed like 5 different guides including official ones.

Comment: The suggestions given by @Bruce Ediger, in the other answer are well worth following